# SSIS extract to Excel loses formatting

Tags: excel, ssis

So my SSIS Package extracts data from SQL Server and I am trying to pump that data into an Excel spreadsheet. I am using an Excel template to do so. I have my data columns left justified and a Copay column defined as Currency format and have changed the template advanced options to suppress 0s.

When I do the extract though, I lose all of my Excel formatting...data columns are centered and my copay column is NOT currency and even displays .00

Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks for your review and am hopeful for a reply.

Comment: in general it is better if you can provide a script showing your code or configuration. You probably should also specify the versions of the software as well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if a row is missing a value in a certain column (null or empty string) then all subsequent rows lose all their formatting for that column.